# Selenium EventFiringWebDriver Navigated event

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium web driver, I want to listen for events occurring in the browser. For instance, when some javascript on the page causes the url to change using `window.location = "...";`

I have a listener attached to the `Navigated` event of my `EventFiringWebDriver`. But this fails to fire when the browser's url is changed. I'm inferring from this that Selenium can't listen to the event in this way?

Is there a proper way to attach to browser or DOM events coming from the browser?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to use the `OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait` object to achieve this. I just have to specify the predicate (a comparison on the browser url) and a timespan. Selenium checks the result once every 500ms until it returns true or the timespan elapses, in which case the test fails. Not quite event driven but it has the desired effect:

```
    private readonly IWebDriver _driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    [Test]
    public void UrlIsCorrect()
    {
        var w = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        w.Until(driver => driver.Url == "http://test.com");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, no, the WebDriver API doesn't support listening for DOM events directly, even with the `EventFiringWebDriver`. You might be able to use JavaScript to attach an event handler to an event, setting a JavaScript variable in the global page context which you could then read from WebDriver, but that's a little convoluted. The `Navigated` event refers to when the WebDriver navigation methods complete.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification around the `EventFiringWebDriver`, you may be interested in the solution I found in the the alternate answer to this question.

Comment: Can Selenium listen to changes in that global variable in event driven form or it can only get its value periodically?

Comment: @ALalavi At present, there is no bidirectional communication with between Selenium and the browser. The WebDriver protocol does not support it, so the answer is, “No, you have to poll for changes.” The W3C working group on the WebDriver specification is currently working on a new version of the WebDriver protocol which _is_ bidirectional, so being notified of changes in an event-driven way should be possible in a future version. Also, version 4 of Selenium (soon to be in beta) will have integration points with the Chrome DevTools Protocol, which may provide some of this functionality.

Comment: @JimEvans thanks for correcting my mistake. I'm eagerly waiting for new releases of Selenium. Meanwhile, I think I can check periodically (for example every 1 second) value of an appended element and clean that value by Selenium (to be later filled by javascript event handler). The only problem i've in my mind is that while getting and remvoing values by Selenium, javascript may wants to add some data to that element and by this conflict i miss some data. In fact, i'm going to listen to websocket messages, created in javascript.