# How to get innerHTML changed event notification using EventFiringWebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

i have a test html page that changes the innerHTML of a div element. 
i am unsuccessful in using selenium.webdriver.support.abstract_event_listener.after_change_value_of (see https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.event_firing_webdriver.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.event_firing_webdriver) to get event notifications when the innerHTML changes. i would like to know where i am going wrong and what is the right mechanism to be intimated of such events.

i have written a small test program in python that uses selenium webdriver and chromedriver. 
the before_navigate_to and after_navigate_to events are fired but the after_change_value_of is not being fired.

```py
#....
#....
def dump_msg(msg):
    print("[%d] %s" % (current_milli_time(), msg))
#....
#....
class MyListener(AbstractEventListener):
    def before_navigate_to(self, url, driver):
        dump_msg("Before navigate to %s" % url)
    def after_navigate_to(self, url, driver):
        dump_msg("After navigate to %s" % url)
    def after_change_value_of(self, element, driver):
        #+---------------------------+
        #| why isnt this working ??? |
        #+---------------------------+
        dump_msg("After change value of %s" % type(element))
#....
#....
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/bin/chromedriver",chrome_options=chrome_options)
ef_driver = EventFiringWebDriver(driver, MyListener())
ef_driver.get("file:///test/test_change.html")
#....
#....
```

test_change.html is as follows

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .boxed1 {
                background-color: yellow;
                opacity:0.4;
            } 
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="foo" class="boxed1"> </div>
        <script>
            document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = Date();
            setInterval(function() { 
                curr_date_time = Date();
                document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = curr_date_time;
                //console.log("updated date_time to " + curr_date_time);
                }, 1000);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

running the program produces 
... 
[1562418297938] Before navigate to file:///test/test_change.html 
[1562418298269] After navigate to file:///test/test_change.html 
...

i expect 'After change value of ...' to be seen, but its not there

Comment: `after_change_value_of()` is called only after selenium changes the value in an input element on the page. `before_navigate_to` and `after_navigate_to` are called before and after you navigate to a url using the `get()` or `.navigate()` methods.

Comment: Thank you. But i would like to know how would i be able to 'trap' the update to the element referred by the "foo" id in the above example. Is there any other method in AbstractEventListener to do this or is any other way/approach ? In general i would like to be notified of any update (add/remove/edit) event occurring in a page.

Comment: check this SO question : https://stackoverflow.com/q/15223001/5074293